# Why does $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \text E \left(W^2(s) W^2(t) \right) \,ds\,dt = 2 \int_0^1 \int_0^t \text E \left(W^2(s) W^2(t) \right) \,ds \,dt$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $W(t)$ denote the standard Wiener Process, i.e. $W(t) \sim \text N(0, t)$ for $t \geq 0$.

I have shown that

$$\text E \left(W^2(s) W^2(t) \right) = st + 2\left[\min(s,\, t)\right]^2$$
and I used it to show that

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \text E \left(W^2(s) W^2(t) \right) \,ds \,dt &= \int_0^1 \left[ \int_0^t \text E \left(W^2(s) W^2(t) \right) \,ds +\int_t^1 \text E \left(W^2(s) W^2(t) \right) \,ds  \right] \,dt \\
&= \int_0^1 \left[ \int_0^t \left( st + 2s^2 \right) \,ds +\int_t^1 \left( st+2t^2 \right) \,ds  \right] \,dt \\
&= \frac{7}{12}
\end{align}

It turns out that

\begin{align}
2 \int_0^1 \int_0^t \text E \left(W^2(s) W^2(t) \right) \,ds \,dt &= 2 \int_0^1 \int_0^t \left( st + 2s^2 \right) \,ds \,dt \\
&= \frac{7}{12}
\end{align}

**Question:**

> I am hoping someone could provide some insight as to why $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \text E \left(W^2(s) W^2(t) \right) \,ds \,dt = 2 \int_0^1 \int_0^t \text E \left(W^2(s) W^2(t) \right) \,ds \,dt$

Comment: The integrals turn out that way.  Exactly what are you looking for?

Comment: I am looking for the reason why the integrals turn out that way.

Comment: You split the integral into two parts depending on $s\lt t$ or $t\lt s$.  Because of symmetry, they are equal, so your result follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand is symmetric in $s$ and $t$.

The second integral only integrates over the region where $s<t$

Comment: If $f(s,\,t) = f(t,\, s)$ then we say the function is symmetric in $s$ and $t$?

Comment: I do, I think it's pretty standard language

Comment: Since we are integrating over the unit square, we could integrate over the triangular region given by $s<t$ and then double it. Is that the proper reasoning?

Comment: yes - that was my reasoning.